# HTTP_SM_USER not working

Tags: php, siteminder

I am trying to get the user logged into my php page which siteminder authentication,for some reason HTTP_SM_USER is not working?
I had the same thing working on a test enviroment but not on the production environment,is there any other way to get the user logged in?

```
<div id="banner">
    <span id="welcome_message"><?php echo getenv('HTTP_SM_USER')?></span>       
</div>
```

Comment: considering how obscure siteminder is, their own forum would be a better place to ask

Comment: are there other options to get the user whos logged in php?

Comment: depends how they "logged in"

Comment: they are logged in using siteminder authentication..they same code works on test enviroment,only in the production am seeing this...there are not differences in test and prod enviroments,how to debug this?

Comment: its obscure, never heard of it before now, so i really suggest you taks this to  their own support forum

Comment: Can any one provide any more info?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get the SM_USER header name instead of HTTP_SM_USER. Also check the value of the DisableUserNameVars parameter in the ACO that is being used. It should be either commented or set to No.